# Get number of subnodes for each XML root node

Tags: c#, xml

This is how the XML looks.

```
<nvd xmlns:scap-core=....>
  <entry id="CVE-2015-0001">
     <vuln:vulnerable-configuration id="http://www.nist.gov/">
        <cpe-lang:logical-test operator="OR" negate="false">
            <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_8:-"/>
            <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:8.1:-"/>
            <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microer_2012:-:gold"/>
            <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:w~~"/>
```

I want to get the number of "cpe-lang:fact-ref" nodes for every entry and show the entry id and the number of nodes.

```
CVE-2015-0001 4
```

This is what I tried

```
var document = XDocument.Load("nvdcve-2.0-2015.xml");
var root = document.Root;
var elements = root.Descendants("entry");
foreach (var entry in elements)
{
    string id = entry.Attribute("id").Value; 
    var cpe = entry.Elements("cpe-lang:fact-ref");
    int nr = 0;
    foreach (var item in cpe)
    {
        nr++;
    }    
Console.WriteLine(id + " " + nr );
}
```

Comment: Should've said that it doesn't loop even once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var elements = root.Descendants("entry");
```

To be:

```
var elements = root.Descendants()
                   .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "entry");
```

You have a namespace on the `entry` node, and since we cannot see it, we cannot help you with it. But, the above will find all nodes named `entry`.

Your line is looking for namespace-less nodes (nodes without a namespace) named `entry`, and there are none.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
var cpe = entry.Descendants("cpe-lang:fact-ref");
```

But you don't need the inner loop, actually:

```
foreach (var entry in elements)
{
    var id = entry.Attribute("id").Value;
    var factRefsCount = entry.Descendants("cpe-lang:fact-ref").Count();
    Console.WriteLine(id + " " + factRefsCount);
}
```

Comment: Still nothing in the console. It doesn't loop.